# Distinct Values from MySQLi Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to only show unique userIds (userIds are (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 etc...) for the query I am running.  I tried using DISTINCT in my query, but it only shows me unique values of the rows that have 2 or more of the same userId.

Is there a way I can use php to only show the unique values.  My weak points are arrays and it makes it more complicated because its using data from a MySQLi query.

Example right now I have with the query now (lets say its GROUP BY rentPaid DESC and the rent total is 800.00 for all users):

```
  userID  rentPaid  rentMonth
  2--------800.00------April  
  1--------500.00------April  
  3--------400.00------April  
  3--------400.00------April  
  1--------200.00------April  
  1--------100.00------April
```

Example desired output:

```
  userID  rentPaid  rentMonth 
  2--------800.00------April  
  1--------500.00------April  
  3--------400.00------April
```

Can I do this with MYSQL because I tried DISTINCT and it wouldn't work, how about PHP?

Query:

```
        SELECT      
            properties.*,
            leases.*,
            users.userId, users.primaryPhone,
            CONCAT(users.userFirstName,' ',users.userLastName) AS user,
            admins.adminName, payments.*
        FROM
            properties
            LEFT JOIN leases ON properties.propertyId = leases.propertyId
            LEFT JOIN assigned ON properties.propertyId = assigned.propertyId
            LEFT JOIN admins ON assigned.adminId = admins.adminId
            LEFT JOIN users ON properties.propertyId = users.propertyId
            LEFT JOIN payments ON properties.propertyId = payments.propertyId
        WHERE
            payments.rentMonth = '$currentMonth' AND
            payments.rentYear = '$currentYear'
```

Edit: Please excuse my formatting, this is my first post.

Edit: Added query....its long, but works lol. I only want **unique** userIds (no double or triple userIds etc...)

Comment: Be a chap and stick the query into your question.

Comment: If the userid has more than one row, which row should it show?

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the entire row selected. So if a user has different `rentPaid` values, it will show each of them because they're not distinct.

Comment: Are you selecting more than just the userID column? Please provide an example of the actual query.

Comment: Added query... Its a long one.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
SELECT userID, MAX(rentPaid) AS maxRentPaid, rentMonth
FROM yourTable
WHERE rentMonth = "April"
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY maxRentPaid
```